# sql last 60 days from last year

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to make a query to get the last 60 days from last year.

I have the current period

```
DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -60, current_timestamp) AND PEDDTEMIS < 'TODAY'
```

What I am trying to get

```
DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -60, DATEDIFF(YEAR,current_timestamp,-1) AND DATE < DATEDIFF(YEAR,'TODAY',-1)
```

The dates I am trying to get:

current: 06/14/2019 - 04/15/2019
last year: 06/14/2018 - 04/15/2018

Appreciate any help

Comment: To be explicit:  do you mean the last 60 days of the previous year (i.e., November 2nd of last year through December 31st), or the 60 days preceding _one year ago today_ ?

Comment: Please provide example data and expected result for that example data. Your usage of `DATEDIFF` makes no sense and clouds what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: What do you mean with _"current: 06/14/2019 - 04/15/2019 last year: 06/14/2018 - 04/15/2018"_? Do you want **both** the current period and last year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are with Oracle. DATEDIFF returns the difference between two dates in YEARS/DAYS etc. What you need is just DATEADDs to subtract a year and to subtract 60 days:

```
DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -60, DATEADD(YEAR,current_timestamp,-1) AND DATE < DATEADD(YEAR,current_timestamp,-1)
```

Comment: Hello Oly, In fact I am using Firebird instead but your query worked for me. I just had to change the order of the paramenters. Thank you.

Comment: perhaps `DATE BETWEEN X AND Y` would had been more idiomatic

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're trying to get the "60 days preceding one year ago today" (though the title of your question suggests something different).

One year ago today should be:  `DATEADD(-1 YEAR TO CURRENT_DATE)`

Sixty days prior should be:  `DATEADD(-60 DAY TO DATEADD(-1 YEAR TO CURRENT_DATE))`

So you are looking for records BETWEEN those two date values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this comes to mind:

```
where date >= '2018-11-02'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I appreciate your reply however my goal is not print the date manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-60, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
```